# Brew MP handset developer activation

Tags: mobile, brew-framework, brewmp

I have a Brew MP which I want to upload my app to. But I understand, it must first be "developer activated" before it will accept my apps. In the Qualcomm tools, I use the Target Manager, but I find no way to activate the phone.

I have a Brewmp.com account, and I [read the instructions](https://developer.brewmp.com/resources/tech-guides/connect-technology-guide/developer-mode/developer-mode-enable#comment-589696), but they are not clear to me.

The Target Manager says "Connected Status: Currently not connected", if that means anything. The phone is connected enough for the tool to display it in the list of the physical devices though.

The handset is a Dopod F3188 running Brew MP 1.0.2.481.

I installed the generic gateway USB driver found in the Brew Tools. However, if I enable a developer mode which is more than USB gateway (+ COM) in the phone, the phone is not recognized by Windows and I can not find any drivers for the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared once I started using a real Windows XP machine instead of a virtual machine. (VirtualBox in this case.)